# Very large SVG rendered blurry in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg, firefox

I'm trying to render a *very* large SVG image inside an `img` tag.
This works fine in Chrome, but Firefox (both Windows and Linux) renders the image blurry as if it was a raster image with much lower resolution.

The problem can be broken down to a simple example:

- SVG image with a view box of 30,000x30,000, showing a diagonal line
- The SVG is displayed in an `img` tag that has a width and height of 30,000px each

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30000 30000'%3E%3Cpath d='M 0,0 L30000,30000' stroke-width='1' stroke='%23000' /%3E%3C/svg%3E" width="30000" height="30000" />
```

This renders as follows (cropped but not scaled):
[image: comparison between rendering in Chrome and Firefox]

What I already tried unsuccessfully:

- different view box sizes
- smaller `img` dimensions but scaled up with CSS transforms (2D/3D)
- `image-rendering: crisp-edges` on the `img`
- `shape-rendering: crispEdges` on the SVG content

Using an `<object>` instead of an `<img>` actually renders the image crisp, but the `<object>` element comes with its own shortcomings and pitfalls. If possible I'd like to keep using the `<img>` element.

Does anybody have hints what might be the problem or ideas for possible solutions?

Comment: One obvious solution would be to avoid having such a large image. Why do you need that bog of an image? Can't you play with the viewbox to make a smaller image behave the same in your application?

Comment: It's difficult to think about possible solutions when we don't know what the ultimate aim is. Could you explain your use case a bit more - e.g. why you need such a big viewbox on the SVG. What do you absolutely need in practice?

Comment: I need to display an SVG image that is uploaded by a user. The user should then be able to zoom in and out of the image. Currently I do this with JS and CSS transforms which works well in Chrome but leads to the described issue in Firefox when the size of the transformed image gets too large (either because the image itself is huge or because it's zoomed in a lot).